# Construction of sequence from convergent susbsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to construct the following?

> A sequence that contains subsequences converging to every point in the infinite set $\{{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ...}\}$ and no subsequences converging to points outside of this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: if there are subsequences converging to $\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, there will necessarily be a subsequence converging to $0$. It *is* possible to make $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ the set of limits of convergent subsequences, however. For instance, you can use the sequence

$$\left\langle 1,1,\frac12,1,\frac12,\frac13,1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,1,\ldots\right\rangle\;.$$